# I am getting max depth exceeded while building the docker image for Microsoft SQL stored procedure

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Step 115/172 :

```
RUN Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance localhost -Database MY_DB -InputFile 'c:\tmp\sql_scripts\dbo.usp_InsertUpdateSSearchDateTimeFilter.sql'
---> Running in 977b55fecdfc
```

Error:

> Max depth exceeded

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because your Dockerfile has exceeded the 125 layers limit for docker images.

If you add the Dockerfile to the question I can help you to simplify it. As a first suggestion, try to group commands in only one RUN

Comment: I grouped the commands on only one run now its working thanks for the response

Comment: :) You're welcome! Remember to mark the answer as correct if it solved the question